# How to add action bar on webview in baseadapter?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to use this code inside getview() of baseadapter to add action bar on webview

```
LinearLayout layWrap = new LinearLayout(context);
layWrap.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
layWrap.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
activity.setContentView(layWrap);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams linearlayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layWrap.setLayoutParams(linearlayoutParams);
WebView webview1=new WebView(context);
layWrap.addView(webview1);
webview1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
ActionBar actionBar =((AppCompatActivity) activity).getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Crashes at actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); returns null, specifically java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does the activity have a ActionBar ? What's the  theme style of the activity ?

Comment: No does not have an ActionBar. There is no style xml i just use it to show an alertdialog. This is a class named CustomAdapter that extends baseadapter. I use  this.context = context; in my CustomAdapter method. Then in getview i use AppCompatActivity activity= (AppCompatActivity)context; then i want to show a webview when a specific button is tapped. I managed to show the webview creating linearlayout programmatically but i want to add buttons on top of the webview. Buttons like "close webview" , "go back" , "refresh page" etc how do i add buttons or actionbar?

Comment: If the activity  does not have a ActionBar , activity).getActionBar() will return null. Could add a actionBar in the xml or let the activity has a actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Could add a ActionBar in the xml of activity Firtst

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color_focused"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/main_navigation"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />
```

Then in the onCreat() of AppCompatActivity:

```
ToolBar bar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(bar);
```

in the main_navigation.xml could add the go back button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="go"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:title="back"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```